# Show date from a chain of characters

Tags: mysql, date, timestamp

this is my first question here, thanks for your support.

I have an old database with many columns, but the is not a DATE column. Yes, my mistake.

But, I have a column called *question_id* with some data, that contains the date and time, like

```
2017113020440370769
```

where first 4 digits are YYYY, next 2 digits are MM and next 2 are DD.

I´m trying to make a query extracting those characters to count how many questions I had on specific dates.

I could, doing this for a specific date:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM questions 
WHERE question_id LIKE '20171228%';
```

But I want to automatize this for TODAY, everyday, not typing each day the YYYYMMDD%

Is it possible? Using CURDATE? Or there is any specific TIMESTAMP I can use?

Thank you very much!

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Extract the date with a regular expression, then you have it as part of your result set to group by.  I'd actually recommend adding a date field, updating the app to set it (doesn't MySQL have a feature to set timestamps automatically?) And then updating the existing empty time stamps once.  But doing it in real should work done on small tables.  Without a schema and example data I can't turn that into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you can build the current dates with wild card as below:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM questions 
WHERE question_id LIKE CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y%m%d'), '%');
```

That's for a specific day; today. For all dates you would have to do an aggregation on the date part of the `question_id` as illustrated below:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(question_id,1,8) ASKED_ON, COUNT(*) NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS
FROM questions 
GROUP BY SUBSTR(question_id,1,8);
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can get today's date with e.g. [CURDATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)
- You can format dates with [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)
- You con concatenate strings with [CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Those are all the bricks you need ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT LEFT('20171228ASD',8) = CURRENT_DATE();


SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM questions 
WHERE LEFT(question_id',8) = CURRENT_DATE();
```